# Does Azure Databricks SparkSQL support recursive queries

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

I am moving data from SQL Server to Azure data lake gen2 and converting SQL queries with recursive queries.

Here is an sample SQL query with recursion using CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
 WITH RECURSIVE AS BOM
          (SELECT p.MItemId AS RootPartNumber,
                  p.MItemId AS PartNumber,
                  NULL AS ParentPartNumber,
                  0    AS BomLevel,
                  1.0  AS Quantity
           FROM   PartItem p

           UNION ALL
           SELECT BOM.RootPartNumber,
                 CAST(BSM.ChildItem AS string) AS PartNumber,
                 CAST(DB.PartNumber AS string) AS ParentPartNumber,
                 BOM.BomLevel + 1  as BomLevel,
                 BSM.Quantity AS Quantity 
           FROM  PartItemBomList BSM
           INNER JOIN BOM  ON BOM.PartNumber = BSM.ParentItem
           INNER JOIN PartItem p           ON p.MItemId = BSM.ChildItem
           WHERE BSM.IsDeleted = 0 
  )
  SELECT * FROM BOM
```

I have tried changing the query embedding the recursion within a FROM clause as shown below with no success.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
          (SELECT p.MItemId AS RootPartNumber,
                  p.MItemId AS PartNumber,
                  NULL AS ParentPartNumber,
                  0    AS BomLevel,
                  1.0  AS Quantity
           FROM   PartItem p
           WHERE p.PartType =    'Cloud-OrderableAssembly' 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT BOM.RootPartNumber,
                 CAST(BSM.ChildItem AS string) AS PartNumber,
                 CAST(DB.PartNumber AS string) AS ParentPartNumber,
                 BOM.BomLevel + 1  as BomLevel,
                 BSM.Quantity AS Quantity 
           FROM  PartItemBomList BSM
           INNER JOIN BOM  ON BOM.PartNumber = BSM.ParentItem
           INNER JOIN PartItem p           ON p.MItemId = BSM.ChildItem
           WHERE BSM.IsDeleted = 0 
  ) as BOM
```

Here is the error I get from Azure Databricks session.

**Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table or view not found: BOM; line 16 pos 22**

Comment: Hi @SQLSylvia did you find a solution or workaround for recursive queries on databricks/spark SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
INNER JOIN BOM  ON BOM.PartNumber = BSM.ParentItem
```

This is the inner query and as I understand the BOM is defined outside , and so this part of the query runs BOM does not exist .

If I were you i could have tried to fix the below query by running directly on the SQL .
The way BOM is referenced below is not correct

```
SELECT p.MItemId AS RootPartNumber,
                  p.MItemId AS PartNumber,
                  NULL AS ParentPartNumber,
                  0    AS BomLevel,
                  1.0  AS Quantity
           FROM   PartItem p
           WHERE p.PartType =    'Cloud-OrderableAssembly' 
           UNION ALL
           SELECT BOM.RootPartNumber,
                 CAST(BSM.ChildItem AS string) AS PartNumber,
                 CAST(DB.PartNumber AS string) AS ParentPartNumber,
                 BOM.BomLevel + 1  as BomLevel,
                 BSM.Quantity AS Quantity 
           FROM  PartItemBomList BSM
           INNER JOIN BOM  ON BOM.PartNumber = BSM.ParentItem
           INNER JOIN PartItem p           ON p.MItemId = BSM.ChildItem
           WHERE BSM.IsDeleted = 0
```